# hyperledger composer deploy and start

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have created a Business network archive. composer deploy and composer start works fine. However, I am not understanding where is it getting deployed ?

Under which channel does it get deployed ?
How can I set endorsement policies for this Business network ?

My understanding of BNA is it is equivalent to chain code which is mentioned under Composer v0.19.0 - Breaking changes section
[enter link description here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under v0.19.0 of Composer (the 'latest' version) the `composer network install` command install the BNA to Peers in the folder `/var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/`. The `composer network start` command creates a new chaincode specific container for each Peer to run the chaincode - the name of the container is made up of the name of the Network and the Version.

The channel used by composer is defined in the Connection Profile (connection.json) being used to install and start the network.  In the Development Fabric the channel used is `composerchannel`.

The endorsement policy can be supplied to the `composer network start` command e.g. `-o endorsementPolicyFile=my-endorsement-policy.json` as described [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.network.start.html).